# C : Convert Char To Float Produce 0.000002?

Tags: c, debugging, casting, char

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main()
{
int a = 8; float b = 3.9; char c='a';
float hasil = a+b+c;
printf("%f", hasil);
getch();
return 0;
}
```

I Get result
108.900002

then, where 0.000002 is it?

If I change to

```
float hasil = a+b;
```

then the result will be
11.900000

Then if we convert char so float, then it will definitely add value 0.000002?
Is that true ? If yes why?

Thanks you

Comment: Floating-point values are stored in binary. The values `3.9` and `108.9` cannot be represented exactly. The actual value is most likely `108.90000152587890625`.

Answer (score 3):

`char c = 'a'` assigns the value `97` to `c`. `97 + 8 + 3.9` is `108.9` in real numbers, but it does not have an exact representation as a float. That's where the spurious `0.000002` comes from. As Keith Thompson points out, the actual value is likely to be `108.90000152587890625`, but the `%f` format specifier probably rounds it.

This is due to the fact that there can only be a finite number of floating point numbers whereas there are uncountably many real numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Neither 11.9 nor 108.9 can be represented exactly in a `float`. You will get better accuracy if you use `double`.

If you change the precision of printing, you will see how accurately those are represented.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int a = 8; float b = 3.9; char c='a';
   float hasil = a+b;
   printf("%.16f\n", hasil);
   hasil = a+b+c;
   printf("%.16f\n", hasil);
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
11.8999996185302734
108.9000015258789062
```

By changing the type to `double`, I get more accurate output:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int a = 8; double b = 3.9; char c='a';
   double hasil = a+b;
   printf("%.16f\n", hasil);
   hasil = a+b+c;
   printf("%.16f\n", hasil);
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
11.9000000000000004
108.9000000000000057
```

Those results are from gcc running on a Linux desktop. I suspect you will get similar, if not exactly same, results in other common compilers too.